# Page index takes too much time to load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using Rails 3.0.7, kaminari gem.

I just built a simple site, with SQLite database and 100,000 rows of data, with just four columns (`ID`, `name`, `created_at`, `updated_at`).

This is my controller:

```
class HclinksController < ApplicationController
  # GET /hclinks
  # GET /hclinks.xml
  def index
    @hclinks = Hclink.page(params[:page])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @hclinks }
    end
  end
end
```

I scaffolded it.

Here's my log:

```
// THIS IS INDEX, WHICH SHOWS ALL THE LIST ITEMS
Started GET "/hclinks" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-05-08 00:59:52 +0800
  Processing by HclinksController#index as HTML
  Hclink Load (391.8ms)  SELECT "hclinks".* FROM "hclinks" LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0
  SQL (4574.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "hclinks"
Rendered hclinks/index.html.erb within layouts/application (178778.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 182775ms (Views: 175845.5ms | ActiveRecord: 4966.6ms)

// THIS IS THE RUBY ON RAILS WELCOME PAGE
Started GET "/hclinks" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-05-08 01:03:13 +0800
  Processing by HclinksController#index as HTML
  Hclink Load (65.3ms)  SELECT "hclinks".* FROM "hclinks" LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0
  SQL (910.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "hclinks"
Rendered hclinks/index.html.erb within layouts/application (1532.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1657ms (Views: 652.5ms | ActiveRecord: 975.9ms)
```

I wonder why the list took so long to respond... How should I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: The time is mostly spent on views. Are you using partials inside a loop on the index page? In development mode, that might take a lot of time on a slower machine.

Comment: The view is simple, just an `ol` list. No partials.

Answer (score 0):

Is this log output from a fresh restart of rails or had the app already run a few requests?

If this wasn't the first request, I'd check if the load time increases on each request.

If it does, you may have a memory leak